# React Native Android assets is not showing when after codepush

Tags: android, react-native, assets, code-push, react-native-code-push

`Images disappear after installing CodePush update`
says
 `If your app is using the React Native assets system to load images (that is the require(./foo.png) syntax), then you MUST release your assets along with your JS bundle to CodePush. is with me`

Can you tell me how to run it as a command for this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/rn-troubleshooting